# Reading Large nText column timed out in SQL

Tags: sql-server

We have nText field in one of our table in which we store XML files. We are able to save large XML around 40-50 MB in nText field. But when we try to read like
select archive_xml from archive where archive_id = 123, it timed out.

Any alternative or any suggestion?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 0):

When you say it's timing out, is it timing out on the server or in your code?  That might impact different solutions.

If it's a server problem, make sure the table has meaningful indexes on the fields you're querying (e.g. archive_id)

If it's timing out in code the "simple" solution is to extend your connection's timeout.  I would try other things first, like improving server performance, because a connection timing out is usually hiding a bigger problem.

Comment: i made connection timeout in web.config file as 600, but it still timesout

Comment: i made it 3600, still its timing out while executing my sp. If i ran this sp on query analyzer it takes almost 4 mins to execute

Comment: @jatin, you need to start looking at indexing your table.  40MB isn't THAT much to pull back.  I was querying millions of rows bringing back a ton of data and it didn't take 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you are executing this query thru some language say C#, make sure you close the unrequired recordsets before executing this.

Query timeout thru query analyzer can be increased by Selecting tools/options and then select Connection tab. Then increase value for 'Query Timeout' parameter.

Also, Indexing this field will greatly reduce the time to execute your query.

Comment: Do you mean that it should have index on archive_xml?

Comment: i made it 3600, still its timing out while executing my sp. If i ran this sp on query analyzer it takes almost 4 mins to execute

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN
If an ntext, text, and image data value is no longer than a Unicode, 4,000 characters; character, 8,000 characters; or binary string, 8,000 bytes, the value can be referenced in SELECT, UPDATE, and INSERT statements much the same way as the smaller data types. For example, an ntext column with a short value can be referenced in a SELECT statement select list the same way an nvarchar column is referenced. Some restrictions that must be observed, such as not being able to directly reference an ntext, text, or image column in a WHERE clause. These columns can be included in a WHERE clause as parameters of a function that returns another data type, such as ISNULL, SUBSTRING or PATINDEX, or in an IS NULL, IS NOT NULL, or LIKE expression.

Handling Larger Data Values
When the ntext, text, and image data values get larger, however, they must be handled on a block-by-block basis. Both Transact-SQL and the database APIs contain functions that allow applications to work with ntext, text, and image data block by block.

The database APIs follow a common pattern in the ways they handle long ntext, text, and image columns:

To read a long column, the application simply includes the ntext, text, or image column in a select list, and then binds the column to a program variable large enough to hold a reasonable block of the data. The application then executes the statement and uses an API function or method to retrieve the data into the bound variable one block at a time.

To write a long column, the application executes an INSERT or UPDATE statement with a parameter marker (?) in the place of the value to be placed in the ntext, text, or image column. The parameter marker (or parameter in the case of ADO) is bound to a program variable large enough to hold the blocks of data. The application goes into a loop where it first moves the next set of data into the bound variable, and then calls an API function or method to write that block of data. This is repeated until the entire data value has been sent.